# div tag hiding behind image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where a div tag that is supposed to show on hover is hidden behind an image. This is how it looks:

[image]

I tried to remake it with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gwxyk/21/
I tried position relative also on '.image-options' but did not turn out right. Also how do i float the small orange box to the right side? I tried float: right; but it did not respond.

Help would be appritiated.

Some arbitrary code since stackoverflow asks for it (its in jsfiddle):

```
.image-options { 
float: right;
```

}

Comment: Im not sure what you want to be the end result? position absolute need a x and y position like top:0px; right:0px; and the parent div needs to be position:relative so the little box doesnt go all over the place. But if you could tell excactly what you are after, it would be helpful.

Comment: The small orange box is not showing on hover because it is hidden behind an image.

Comment: I can see from the fiddle that you havent closed your div properly. Look here. I have changed some of your css and ended the div for you. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwxyk/32/)

Comment: Do you want the image-options to appear on top of the picture, or to the right of the picture?

Comment: On top of the image and in the right corner.

Comment: If you put your .image-options div markup after the image it will appear on top of the image without fiddling with z-index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand exactly what you require to happen. However have you tried using the z-index property? Both the div and the image will need to be positioned relatively or absolutely, then apply a higher z-index to the element that you want to appear in front. So you could apply z-index: 1 to the image and z-index: 100 to the div.

Comment: This gave somewhat satisfying result. I got the small orange box to show above the image. However the dropdown that is generated by clicking the small orange box is limited to the parent div. maybe I should try relative. Also how can I float the orange box to the top right corner?

Comment: regarding the drop-down, could try giving parent div overflow: visible. As for the orange box, if it is positioned absolutely, and parent div is positioned relatively / absolutely, give small orange box positioning of top: 0; right: 0;

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

Add `top:0` to `.image-options` and interchange the place of image and inner div.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwxyk/42/)

Comment: You need both top/bottom and left/right for position:absolute to work in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, i think this will help you out.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmP2x/

You dont have to do this with jQuery, use CSS as much as you can to tidy up your code.

css:

```
 .testclass {
    width: 105px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid rgba(140,140,140,1);
}

.image-options {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,128,64,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
    overflow: none;
    display: none;
}
.image {
    background-image: url('http://www.placehold.it/105X80');
    width: 105px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
}
.image:hover .image-options {
    display: block;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="testclass">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="image-options"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```